# PWA2APK titlebar is visible. Is it mandatory to upload assetlinks.json to the website?

Tags: android, google-play, apk, progressive-web-apps

I used the PWA2APK to convert the website to an APK.

We were earlier not using assetlinks.json and the older version of the app doesn't have any title bar. The older version is using SDK 29.

I upgraded the SDK to 33 to support latest android versions and able to build and generate apk successfully. But after installing the APK on a device, I can see the title/url bar visible either on the top or on the bottom.

With the upgrade to newer version, is the assetlinks.json is mandatory to be uploaded on https://example.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json  and available publicly?

I saw the following also during the generation.

[PWA2APK_Snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viHer.png)

Can I hide the title/url bar without doing any modifications on the server?

I have used the original keystore of the app. And also verified the SHA256 of apk and play console and they are same.

I tried setting few values in the build.gradle.

[build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/al8CN.png)

And following in styles.xml

[styles.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPlhI.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.